# How to always show map view annotation callouts?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

How do you always show the annotation callouts, i.e. don't hide them when you tab the map view?

[image: annotation callout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callout is shown when an `MKAnnotationView` is selected and the view's `canShowCallout` property is set to `YES`.

It is then hidden when that `MKAnnotationView` is deselected. This occurs by tapping another annotation view, or by tapping outside of the currently selected annotation view.

As the delegate of `MKMapView` (conforming to `MKMapViewDelegate`), you are told when an annotation view is selected and deselected, but it's too late to do anything about it.

If you want to not deselect an annotation view, you should subclass `MKAnnotationView` and override the `setSelected:animated:` method and stop the annotation view from being deselected.

Comment: I tried overriding setSelected:animated: and it didn't work =/

Answer (score 2):

Resetting the annotations also will bring the callout to view state true.

```
    [mapView removeAnnotation: currentMarker];
    [mapView addAnnotation:currentMarker];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Zumry Mohammed for this idea. This solution in swift works for me:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let ann = view.annotation else {return}
    mapView.removeAnnotation(ann)
    mapView.addAnnotation(ann)
    mapView.selectAnnotation(ann, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set isSelected property to true on viewFor annotation method and that is all.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    
    let annotationV = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    annotationV.image = UIImage(named: "ZeusSurveyMarkerTaskIcon", in: Bundle(for: ZsurveysGeofenceLocationMapView.self), compatibleWith: nil)
    annotationV.canShowCallout = true
    annotationV.isSelected = true
    
    return annotationV
}
```